# Additional data in UITypeEditor EditValue

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, propertygrid, uitypeeditor

I have some problems accessing contextual data in a custom `UITypeEditor`. I'm using a `PropertyGrid` to display some settings using Windows Forms. The `SelectedObject` of the `PropertyGrid` contains a `List<A>`. Type `A` has a property for which I have created a custom editor that needs some external information to be able to customize it for different instances of `PropertyGrid`.

I've attempted the approach of using the `IServiceProvider` passed to `EditValue` to access a custom service that contains the data. It was suggested by ironic in an answer here [Passing objects to a UITypeEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010617/passing-objects-to-a-uitypeeditor?rq=1) but I haven't managed to get it to work. `GetService` always returns null inside `EditValue`. I think my problem is that the `ISite` I set as `PropertyGrid.Site` isn't reachable in the nested `UITypeEditor` where the information is needed (when I attempt to get the service using `GetService` inside the list's editor's `EditValue` method it works).

Does anyone know how to make my `ISite` propagate to nested `UITypeEditor`s?

Some pseudo code:

```
public interface IMyService {
    object GetUserData();
}

public class MyService : IMyService {
    private object userData;
    public MyService(object ud) {
        userData = ud;
    }

    public object GetUserData() {
        return userData ;
    }
}

public class MySite : ISite {
    private object userData;

    public MySite(object ud) {
        userData = o;
    }

    ...

    public object GetService(Type serviceType) {
        if (serviceType == typeof(IMyService))
        {
            return (IMyService) new MyService(userData);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

public class A {
    [Editor(typeof(EditorA), typeof(UITypeEditor)]
    public object SomeEditedProperty { ... }
}



public EditorA : UITypeEditor {
    ...
    public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
    }
    ...
    public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext c, IServiceProvider p, object v) {
        // This always returns null!
        object myService = p.GetService(typeof(IMyService));  
        ...
        object myData = myService.GetUserData();
        ...
    }
}

public class EditedObject {
    [Editor(...)]
    public List<A> Stuff { ... }
}

// somewhere
object userData = new object();
propertyGrid.Site = new MySite(userData);

EditedObject objectToEdit = new EditedObject();
...
propertyGrid.SelectedObject = objectToEdit;
```

Comment: IWindowsFormsEditorService editorService =(IWindowsFormsEditorService)p.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService)); and u must override GetEditStyle or else it will return UITypeEditorEditStyle.None

Comment: I'm specifying the modal edit style, clarified that in the code. When I call GetService like you say I get a PropertyGridView and the parent of that is a PropertyGrid. However, when I look at what GetHashCode() returns for the property grid, it is not the same property grid as the one I set the Site property for. What gives?